# Allow Contributor to change the author of his own post?

Tags: capabilities

Is it possible to let a contributor change the author of his own posts?
I realize this will effectively lock them out of the post, that's what i want.
I want them to be able to change the author once they are done editing.

Comment: Just wondering here whether there is another way to achieve the business need.  Giving a non-editor/admin ability to assign any other author their post seems a bit broad.   Is there a predefined list of authors they can assign as the 'author'?  Is there any defined relationship between the contributor and  allowed authors? Or can they choose any author they like?

Comment: I also note that this will not 'publish' their post.  It therefore sounds like the intention is to mimic some sort of workflow where the contributor is assigning the post to an author rather than than say an editor selecting the 'pending' posts for review.  If your authors could be editors then perhaps go with wp as is and perhaps use tags rather to communicate or highlight which editors should pickup which posts?

Comment: Ah, you say "lock them out of the post, that's what i want".  Is that more important? That once they 'submit for review', they are no longer able to edit?  Is it necessary to mess with 'authors' ?  Or would some non-public status work?  Maybe using https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Custom_Status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pitfalls:

Even though it's possible to allow an author (or contributor) to assign another author to his/her own post using `user_has_cap` filter hook and some related CODE, however, **this approach itself is fundamentally flawed**. So even if you take all necessary security measures, it's still a vulnerability because it breaks the capability architecture all together.

Let me give you an example scenario: say a user with author role has less than honorable intent and spams another author with a lot of posts (perhaps using a script). The next time the destination author logs in, s/he will see all those posts in his/her name! This will continue as the other author has no way of stopping it! So we must find an alternative approach that doesn't have this flaw.

### A better approach:

If the author change is a necessary feature, then a better approach is to involve the other author (or a higher power user like other editors or admins) within the process of author change, so that the initiating author may not be able to spam the destination author.

To achieve that, we'll let the initiating author choose the destination author from the editor, but we'll not change the post author straight way. Instead, at the time of author change, we'll save a custom post meta that'll save the destination author id. Then within the admin panel, we'll have a post sub menu, where all posts with the author change request will appear. Only the destination author and users with `edit_others_post` capability (like editors, admins etc.) will have access to this author change request UI. From the UI, the user with proper access will approve the change and only then the final author change will happen.

### What happens to posts while in the approval queue?

CODE implementation may vary depending on the requirement, however, without any other CODE implementation, the initiating authors will be able to modify the post or even revert the author change request within the window of the approval process. They will be locked out of the post as soon the the author change request is approved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a second answer because my first approach got voted down and this one didn't get proper attention.

The idea is to create custom meta box that lists all the users and changes the author in `save_post` hook. This way you don't mess with users capabilities and the author change happens when the posts is already saved. Also the additional profit is that you can control the list of users that are available in author dropdown. Steps to follow:

**Register meta box:**

```
function wpse313020_add_custom_box() {

    // Bail out for users other than contributors
    if ( ! user_can( get_current_user_id(), 'contributor' ) ) {
        return;
    } 

    // Register custom meta box
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse313020_author_override',
        'Change Author', // metabox title
        'wpse313020_author_ovveride_box_html', // callbac function
        'post' // a post type you want to show the metabox on
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wpse313020_add_custom_box');
```

**Build markup for your meta box:**

```
/**
 * HTML for custom meta box
 */
 function wpse313020_author_ovveride_box_html() {
    // you can modify the list of users by passing additional args to get_users()
    $users = get_users();
    ?>
    <label for="wpse313020_author_override_id">Select post author</label><br />
    <select name="wpse313020_author_override_id" id="wpse313020_author_override_id" class="postbox">
        <option value="">Select user...</option>
        <?php
        // get post ID on admin edit screen and retrieve saved post meta
        $post_id     = is_admin() && isset( $_GET['post'] ) ? absint( wp_unslash( $_GET['post'] ) ) : '';
        $saved_value = ! empty( $post_id ) ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpse313020_author_override', true ) : '';

        foreach ( $users as $user ) {
            echo sprintf( '<option value="%1$d" %2$s>%3$s</option>', absint( $user->ID ), selected( $saved_value, absint($user->ID, false ) ), esc_html( $user->display_name ) );
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
 }
```

**Hook into `save_post` to save data and override the author:**

```
/**
 * Save custom post meta and override the post author
 */
function wpse313020_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

    if ( array_key_exists('wpse313020_author_override_id', $_POST ) ) {
        // save post meta with author ID
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpse313020_author_override', absint( $_POST['wpse313020_author_override_id'] ) );

        // now modify the post author, we need to unhook the current function to prevent infinite loop
        // you could add additional check here to see if the current author is not the same as chosen author

        remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse313020_save_postdata' );

        $updated_data = [
            'ID'          => $post_id,
            'post_author' => absint( $_POST['wpse313020_author_override_id'] ),
        ];

        wp_update_post( $updated_data );

        add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse313020_save_postdata' );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'wpse313020_save_postdata');
```

**NOTE**
Remember to add nonce field and check it on post save. 
Also you might consider using other hooks instead of `save_post`, i.e. `pre_post_update` or `wp_insert_post_data`, to process data on initial post save.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The author dropdown box [will only show](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L322) when the user has the `edit_others_posts` capability. However, you don't want to give this capability to authors by default, for obvious reasons. The solution is to give this capability only under specific circumstances, namely when he is editing one of his own posts. Because the capability is written to the database you must also make sure it is removed on any other page.

This is a matter of precise timing. You want to change the capability **after** WP has decided the contributor has the right to edit the post, but **before** the form of the edit page (`post.php`) is generated. A suitable hook is [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init).

Like this:

```
add_action ('admin_init', 'wpse313020_change_author');
function wpse313020_change_author () {
  global $pagenow;
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  // only do this if current user is contributor
  if ('contributor' == $current_user->roles[0]) {
    // add capability when we're editing a post, remove it when we're not
    if ('post.php' == $pagenow)
       $current_user->add_cap('edit_others_posts')
    else
       $current_user->remove_cap('edit_others_posts');
    }
  }
```

I haven't tested the code, so it may be buggy, but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to achieve what you need by filtering the contributor meta capabilities and it seems to work fine. All I do here is adding the `edit_others_posts` capability for contributors when WordPress requests for it.

However, I'd say it's a bit hacky solution to me and I'm not sure if it's entirely safe. From what I've checked after putting my filter to `functions.php` WordPress doesn't allow contributors to edit other users posts in other contexts then the one you've asked for. It seems fine, but we can't really explicitly check if the current user is the author of currently edited post (you wouldn't be able to save the post as different user if that conditional check would be added to the function) - that worries me.

```
/**
 * author_cap_filter()
 *
 * Filter on the current_user_can() function.
 * This function is used to explicitly allow contributors to change post authors
 *
 * @param array $allcaps All the capabilities of the user
 * @param array $cap     [0] Required capability
 * @param array $args    [0] Requested capability
 *                       [1] User ID
 */
function author_cap_filter( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {

    // Bail out if we're not dealing with right capability:
    if ( ! in_array( $args[0], [ 'edit_others_posts' ] ) ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }

    // Bail out for users who are not contributors
    if ( ! user_can( $args[1], 'contributor' ) ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }

    // Bail out for users who can already edit others posts:
    if ( isset( $allcaps['edit_others_posts'] ) && $allcaps['edit_others_posts'] ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }

    // overwrite 'edit_others_posts' capability
    $allcaps[ $args[0] ] = true;

    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'author_cap_filter', 100, 3 );
```

Comment: Please note that, granting authors `edit_others_posts` capability will essentially allow them to edit other's posts. We can just as well make the author to an editor, that's probably better than giving them a higher capability. The second solution is a possibility, but needs some more work, IMHO.

Comment: I feel like the downvote here is not fair, I'm actually pointing out both things in my answer stating that first solution is not safe and pointing out that second one needs more work, but I believe that it's helpful as it shows a working solution that the OP can improve (i don't think that answering a question on WPSE should mean providing a production ready code snippets). Also, it would be useful if you could be more precise and point out what could be improved or even edit my post if you mean some small tweaks. Cheers!

Comment: Also, you're not entirely right about `edit_others_posts` always allowing editing other user's posts. Please test the code from my answer - even with the filter in place, the capability check `if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )` in https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/56c162fbc9867f923862f64f1b4570d885f1ff03/wp-admin/post.php#L123 still returns false. Again, I do agree that it's not the safe solution as mentioned in my answer, but I thought it's worth mentioning as it actually works. (sorry for two comments in a row, I didn't fit the charachter limit)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, install plugin User Role Editor (https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).

Second, using the plugin create a new role called Post Manager, for instance:

[image]

After creating the new role you will be able to edit its capabilities. Now, is the moment you solve your problem, but you have to decide between two options:

(do not worry about the contributor role, yet)

**First:**

- Give your new role two extra capabilities, `edit_others_posts` and `publish_posts`.
- This way, your contributor will be able to edit only posts that are not published (just Pending and Draft posts). So if the contributor just change the post author they will still be able to edit the post. They will only be blocked from editing the post after publishing it. It also means that if the contributor publishes the post and forget to change the author, they will lose the opportunity of changing the post author.

**Second:**

- Give your new role just one extra capability, `edit_others_posts`.
- This way works like the first one, BUT here your contributor can't publish which means they can't publish and forget to change the author. Here, someone would have to publish the post.

After deciding click on "Update". Your new role should now have the `read` capability plus the one(s) you chose.

Now, go to your *contributor user profile page*, and at the end of the page give them extra roles (User Role Editor feature):

[image]

Now, every user which is a Contributor and a Post Manager will be able to change the post author of non-published posts. And depending on your previous choice the user might also publish posts, and if they do they can't edit the post anymore.

**IMPORTANT!!!**

> I showed you a solution creating a new role to preserve the default capabilities of the Contributor. **If you want (not wise), you could skip the Post Manager creation and using User Role Editor you would just edit the Contributor capabilities directly**.

And just for the record, by default WordPress only allows the `edit_others_posts` capability to change the post author. See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php line 1483.

Comment: this makes the user an editor, no need for installing plugins for that, just use the user admin. Anyway, this is not what the OP asks for.

Comment: This solution explicitly allows the Contributor to change the post author. So, yes, it is what he asked for. Second, by default, the Editor has more than 20 capabilities assigned to it. My solution doesn't make the Contributor an Editor. Let the one who asked decide if my answer solves their issue. Please, think twice about your downvote.

Comment: the OP asks for away a **contributor** to do things. Your solution is to make him **editor** that can change authors everywher abd those break security